# Как в Node.js скачать список файлов?

Tags: javascript, node.js

допустим есть какой-то список файлов
https://vk.com/images/emoji/D83DDC38.png
https://vk.com/images/emoji/D83CDF40.png
https://vk.com/images/emoji/D83EDD8B.png
их может быть много, даже миллион штук.

нужен такой скрипт, чтобы его можно было запустить, и он все эти файлы скачал на компьютер. при этом может интернет оборваться, или сайт перестать отвечать, нужно чтобы скрипт не беспокоился, а подождал когда сайт или интернет сново заработают, и дальше бы продолжил скачивание, пока всё не скачает.

Comment: Непонятно зачем это делать на ноде. Полно готовых программ для скачивания.

Comment: потомучто на ноде это проще, программу ещё надо изучать.

Comment: если бы это было проще, вы бы не задавали тут этот вопрос. Для тупого "скачать пачку файлов" изучать ничего не надо

Comment: я нашел в интернете как скачать 1 файл, я поставил это в цикл, и у меня все файлы не скачались.

Comment: Вот именно поэтому не нужно писать свой велосипед с треугольными колесами. Предусмотреть всевозможные проблемы очень сложно.